# Generating time intervals in R to the scale of minutes

Tags: r

I want to create a function generator(start_date,number of dates) in R which generates n dates each with interval of 5 mins(say). How can I achieve that in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within`lubridate` package you can use `minutes`:

```
 satrt_date + minutes(seq(1,N,5))
```

Example creating a vector of 100 dates starting from Now:

```
Sys.Date()+minutes(seq(1,100,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `seq`, which has a `.POSIXt` method built in:

```
seq(as.POSIXlt("1910/1/1"), length.out = 10, by = "10 mins")
 [1] "1910-01-01 00:00:00 EST" "1910-01-01 00:10:00 EST" "1910-01-01 00:20:00 EST" "1910-01-01 00:30:00 EST"
 [5] "1910-01-01 00:40:00 EST" "1910-01-01 00:50:00 EST" "1910-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "1910-01-01 01:10:00 EST"
 [9] "1910-01-01 01:20:00 EST" "1910-01-01 01:30:00 EST"
```

see `?seq.POSIXt` for more details